# How many EC2 instances to deploy Tornado and MongoDB webapp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to cloud computing and am trying to deploy my Tornado+MongoDB webapp on AWS and configure it to auto scale. Can I start off with Tornado and MongoDB on the EC2 instance, or must they be deployed on separated instances?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly "start off" by running Tornado and MongoDB on the same system; but presumably if you're trying to design for auto scaling, you'll want Tornado and MongoDB on separate instances so you can scale your Tornado and MongoDB resources independently to match the respective demands of your application at scale.